# My setup.py is not working -- install fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils

So, I've been trying this whole week to write a proper `setup.py`, and ended up with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
from codecs import open
from os import path

# Get the version number
from sql_tools2 import __version__

__author__ = 'Pandu POLUAN (pepoluan)'
__copyright__ = '(C) 2015, Pandu POLUAN'
__maintainer__ = 'pepoluan'
__email__ = 'pepoluan@gmail.com'
__status__ = 'Development'
__credits__ = ['pepoluan']

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='sql_tools2',
    version=__version__,
    description='Tools to manipulate and analyze SQL Queries before execution.',
    long_description=long_description,
    url='https://bitbucket.org/pepoluan/sqltools2',
    author='Pandu POLUAN',
    author_email='pepoluan@gmail.com',
    license='MPL 2.0',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: System Administrators',
        'Programming Language :: SQL',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Quality Assurance',
        'Topic :: Database',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Mozilla Public License 2.0 (MPL 2.0)',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7'
    ],
    keywords='sql subquery',
    packages=['sql_tools2'],
    install_requires=['sqlparse'],
    extras_require={
        'dev': ['pytest'],
        'test': ['pytest'],
    },
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Now if I execute `setup.py install`, I see the module being installed.

However, another Python program (same virtualenv) cannot import:

```
>>> import sql_tools2
ImportError: no module named sql_tools2
```

I am using **PyCharm** as the IDE. Interestingly, if I type `import` and wait for auto-completion, PyCharm indeed offered `sql_tools2` as one of the modules it recognized.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you find your package in `pip freeze` output?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to do a `pip freeze` within PyCharm (and in Windows). But if I open `File > Settings > Project: > Project Interpreter`, I can see "`sql-tools2`" listed...

Comment: What is your interpreter? Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm on windows, and yes I've created a virtualenv to test the installation of the package.